# Найти строку, начиная от другой строки

Tags: linux, sed, awk

Есть файл типа

```
/api/foo:
  response:
    500
/api/bar:
  response:
    200
/api/baz:
  response:
    500
```

Как можно с помощью sed или awk сделать следующую выборку:

- Найти все строки с `500`.
- Для каждой такой строки идти назад, пока не найдём строку с `/api/`.
- Распечатать эту строку.

То есть, для файла выше результат должен быть:

```
/api/foo:
/api/baz:
```

Я знаю, что в sed можно распечатать строку с помощью `/500/p`, но как вместо этого запустить "поиск назад"? Или решить задачу иным алгоритмом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример того, как это можно сделать:

```
$ sed -n -e '/\/api/ { h; }; /500/ { x; p; }' -- test.txt
```

Пояснение:

- Если нашли `/api`, кладём во временный буфер (`h`).
- Если нашли `500`, достаём из временного буфера (`x`) и печатаем (`p`).

---

Если `500` встречается под `/api` несколько раз, предыдущая команда выведет лишние `500`. В таком случае лучше использовать более понятную команду awk:

```
awk '/\/api/ { a = $0; } /500/ { if (a) { print a; a = ""; } }' test.txt
```

Comment: Сложно. В два матч выражения *sed* это умеет.

Comment: @0andriy Если знаете, как сделать проще, покажите пожалуйста в форме ответа?

Comment: https://www.shellhacks.com/sed-awk-print-lines-between-two-patterns/